# xclock - always on top feature?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I want to have a clock which can always sit on top of other windows so that I can always see the time. I was playing with xclock but I am not sure if it has an always on top feature?

I am running an Ubuntu 10.04 Gnome desktop. If xclock does not have this feature, is there another application that can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345224/x11-xlib-window-always-on-top is a duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

This is a function provided by your WM, not the application.
E.g. with regular Gnome, launch xclock, move the mouse pointer above xclock titlebar and right-click: a short menu will appear, and one of its options is "Always on Top". Select it and you are done.