# How to make a python gtk app "dock" on top of other apps?

Tags: python, gtk

I'd like for this python gtk app to be "docked" at the top of the screen. Is there a way to disable the close, maximize, and minimize buttons and keep it on top of the other applications?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import gtk
import webkit
DEFAULT_URL = 'http://webpage.com'
class SimpleBrowser:
def __init__(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.connect('delete_event', self.close_application)
    self.window.set_default_size(1024, 125)
    vbox = gtk.VBox(spacing=5)
    vbox.set_border_width(5)
    self.txt_url = gtk.Entry()
    self.txt_url.connect('activate', self._txt_url_activate)
    self.scrolled_window = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    self.webview = webkit.WebView()
    self.scrolled_window.add(self.webview)
    vbox.pack_start(self.scrolled_window, fill=True, expand=True)
    self.window.add(vbox)
def _txt_url_activate(self, entry):
    self._load(entry.get_text())
def _load(self, url):
    self.webview.open(url)
def open(self, url):
    self.txt_url.set_text(url)
    self.window.set_title('%s' % url)
    self._load(url)
def show(self):
    self.window.show_all()
def close_application(self, widget, event, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    url = sys.argv[1]
else:
    url = DEFAULT_URL
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
browser = SimpleBrowser()
browser.open(url)
browser.show()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, Maximize & Minimize in the toolbar are part of window manager decorations. If you want to get rid of them then disable decorations using [`gtk.Window.set_decorated`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-decorated) and setting the decorations settings to false. Regarding always on top you can try [`gtk.Window.set_keep_above`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-keep-above). This again is a "hint" to the window manager. There is a possibility that your window manager may choose to ignore it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482565/how-to-make-python-window-run-as-always-on-top) discusses about "always on top" window and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345224/x11-xlib-window-always-on-top) discusses more about X11 and the window manager hint to set the window as "always on top".
Hope this helps!